# image loading issues in cv2.HoughCircles

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, hough-transform

Im working with 128 x 128 arrays of type float32. These arrays are pulled from binary files and I'm attempting to locate disks in each array.

When I try to use the HoughCircles example code:

```
img = Image.fromarray(fa)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
# draw the center of the circle
cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
```

I recieve the following error:

> File "", line 2, in 
>       cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
>
> TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

If I don't convert to image with Image.fromarray, I recieve the following error indicating that I still am not working with the correct type.

> File "", line 1, in 
>       circles = cv2.HoughCircles(fa,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
>
> error: OpenCV(3.4.4)
>   /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp:1736:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_image.empty() && _image.type() ==
>   CV_8UC1 && (_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat()) in function
>   'HoughCircles'

Comment: `Image.fromarray` is counterproductive -- you're using OpenCV, which doesn't accept PIL image objects as input. According to documentation, `cv2.HoughCircles` requires "8-bit, single-channel, grayscale input image" -- if you're feeding it an array of floats, it will complain. You need to cast the array to `np.uint8` including any necessary scaling.

Comment: Thanks! Ill update once I have a chance to test that fix.

Answer (score 3):

Houghcircles take 8-bit, single-channel, grayscale input image.  and you array is 128 x 128 arrays of type float32. So try changing the type.

And for sanity check display your image, before and after this operation

img = Image.fromarray(fa)

Comment: Testing the 8bit downscale, missed that in the documentation. Will update once I find out if it works!

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to convert your image to gray :

```py
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

If you have a 64-bit image you can convert it to 8-bit by using this method :

```py
8_image = np.uint8(64_image)
```